# What domains does Azure use?

Tags: azure

I know different types of services on Azure get different domain names.   for instance VMs use *.CloudApp.Net, and databases use *.database.windows.net.

What are the rest of them.  I can't find a list anywhere.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not a comprehensive list, but this should get you started. Some of them are REST API endpoints.

`Cloud Services/Virtual Machines`: *.cloudapp.net

`Azure Websites`: *.azurewebsites.net

`Blob Storage`: *.blob.core.windows.net

`Table Storage`: *.table.core.windows.net

`Queue Service`: *.queue.core.windows.net

`SQL Database`: *.database.windows.net

`Access Control Service`: *.accesscontrol.windows.net

`Service Bus`: *.servicebus.windows.net

`Azure Active Directory`: graph.windows.net/*

Please feel free to edit the answer and add more services.

From kwill:

`File Service`: *.file.core.windows.net

`Mobile Services`: *.azure-mobile.net

`Media Services`: *.origin.mediaservices.windows.net

`Visual Studio Online`: *.visualstudio.com

`BizTalk Services`: *.biztalk.windows.net

`CDN`: *.vo.msecnd.net

`API Management`: *.azure-api.net

`Traffic Manager`: *.trafficmanager.net

`Active Directory`: *.onmicrosoft.com

`Management Services`: *.management.core.windows.net

Answer (score 5):

Adding a few more to Gaurav's list:

`File Service`: *.file.core.windows.net

`Mobile Services`: *.azure-mobile.net

`Media Services`: *.origin.mediaservices.windows.net

`Visual Studio Online`: *.visualstudio.com

`BizTalk Services`: *.biztalk.windows.net

`CDN`: *.vo.msecnd.net

`API Management`: *.azure-api.net

`Traffic Manager`: *.trafficmanager.net

`Active Directory`: *.onmicrosoft.com

`Management Services`: *.management.core.windows.net

Comment: I think it would be much better to edit Gaurav's answer than to post a separate one.

Comment: Would he earn rep for his contribution by editing the existing answer?  If not, the application's design encourages a separate answer.

Comment: @slypete: Yes, he would, but not as much.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will also need
`*microsoftonline.com` for Azure Active Directory Connect (for auth)